# Is any way I can define where to look for images when rendering img tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Like any other mvc project, I have used img tag and src="~/Images/test.png" all over my project to display different images in different pages. Is there any ideas to control where to look for images (assume I have hosted these images in different place) instead of looking into images folder before rendering?

Comment: Update src to whereever you want to point to (eg: <img src="https://myurl.com/myimage.jpg" >)

Comment: Thanks Ajith.  Is there any event in code behind gets triggered every time before an image gets rendered so I can decide where to render from either from images folder or from external url. I hope I explained much more clear this time.

Answer (score 1):

pass the location in as part of the model.

```
<img src='@string.Format("~/{0}/test.png", url)'>
```

Comment: Thanks terrencep. I can amend all img tags to determine where to look for images based on model value. How about css pointing to images folder?